# How can I efficiently prune and merge nodes in a quadtree?

Tags: c++, quadtree

I'm using a quadtree to allow me to efficiently gather particles in a certain 2D area. The particles fade over time and eventually die out, and so I have a need to remove them from the quadtree as they die.

The problem I'm facing is how best to then prune the quadtree to remove empty nodes, and to merge nodes when they no longer have enough particles to justify being split.

My first thought is that I would recursively traverse the tree, checking each of the child nodes. If all 4 nodes are empty, then I would pass that back up the call stack with a flag (true for empty, false if not), otherwise, I would check the number of particles in each of the child nodes, and if they're all less than *MAX_PER_NODE,* pull all the particles into the parent and delete the children.

Perhaps something like the following (this pseudocode is quite literally stream of consciousness as I write this, so take it with a grain of salt):

```
class QuadTreeNode
{
     public bool prune();
     public void deleteChildren(); //just assume it does what you expect...
     private:
     std::vector<ParticleType> particles;
     std::vector<QuadTreeNode*> children; // size <= 4

};

bool QuadTreeNode::prune()
{
    bool allChildrenEmpty = true;
    for(QuadTreeNode & n : children)
    {
        allChildrenEmpty &= n.prune();
    }
    //Merging could be handled by returning the number of particles instead of true/false
    //If the total number of particles falls below the max per bucket, pull the particles into the
    //current node and delete the children...
    if(allChildrenEmpty) this.deleteChildren();
    return allChildrenEmpty && (!this.particles.size());    

}
```

However, this seems like it would be inefficient, as I feel it would require me to touch every node in the tree (though I guess that's better than visiting *every* particle).

Is there a better way to implement this prune-and-merge operation?

Comment: Do the particles all have the same lifetime? If so you can put them in four queues, one for each quadrant. You then only have to check if the earliest particles have expired.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not heavily RAM-constrained, you could add a weight counter to each node, representing the total number of particles in itself and its decendents.  Whenever you insert or delete a particle you update it, which isn't actually expensive because you're pulling those nodes into L1 *anyway*.

Then when you delete you can also check if weight < MAX_PER_NODE, and cleanup if so.  You can do all this on the way down the tree, so there are still no extra main memory hits.